# Accounting - Multi-tenancy table

Tags: sql-server, multi-tenant, saas

I have a question about designing multi-tenancy table for Customer Table in an accounting application. The customer Number of each Tenant start based on Tenant setting let's say 10000, this number will increment automatically, then if I use auto increment for Customer ID field in the table, all tenant will use the same range 10000 and up. unique customer id for each tenant

Tenant 1 Start from 10000 
Tenant 2 start from 10000 
Tenant 3 start from 100

and so on.
Customer numbers will be incremented automatically for each tenant.

any idea?

Thanks

Comment: what is the question

Comment: Is there a restriction that you foresee that Tenant3 cannot have more than 899 customers. Any idea on the logic. Regarding how to generate, just get the customerid max from SQL Server and then increment by 1 and then use it for the new customers. HTH